# Rails, a way to render everything my app has in one json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to render everything my app has to json, so I can pass it to android studio.
I have a general controller and a method initialize and I want to pass everything from there.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
    def initialize

        @articles = Article.all
        @areas = Area.all
        @languages = Language.all
        #now what?
    end
end
```

I know it's probably a starter's question but I can't find a simple example to see how this works. Or I'm not searching right. Do I need a gem, or I can do that with *render :json => @data * or something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hash and return all together. like

```
 data_json = { articles: @articles, areas: @areas, languages: @languages }

 render json: data_json
```

Comment: I tried it but I get `undefined method variant for nil:NilClass`
Do you happen to know what causes this?

Comment: I posted the error trace. The variables are not Nil if this is what you are saying.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed that problem, this post answers my question anyway, so everything is fine!

Answer (score 1):

add in your controller **respond_to :json**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    def initialize

        @articles = Article.all
        @areas = Area.all
        @languages = Language.all
        #now what?
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
What command do I use to render them all together?